# Can a mat-checkbox be used as a matStepperNext?

Tags: checkbox, angular7, stepper

I want a step within a stepper to have an agreement, but don't want the extra button that says "I agree with what I just checked to agree to". Just click on the checkbox and go.

Using the standard Angular example, I swapped out the button for a checkbox and the stepper doesn't move forward.

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="isLinear = !isLinear" id="toggle-linear">
  {{!isLinear ? 'Enable linear mode' : 'Disable linear mode'}}
</button>
<mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Agree with Terms</ng-template>
      <div>
        <mat-checkbox matStepperNext formControlName="firstCtrl" required> I agree </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    You are now done.
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Expect to click the checkbox and have the stepper move directly to step 2.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The key word, matStepperNext, appears to not apply to checkboxes. However, if in the checkbox HTML, where you include #stepper in your stepper's div...

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper [linear]="isLinear">you include a (change) event calling a function...
```

You can add a (change) event that calls a function with that name...

```
<mat-checkbox matStepperNext (change)="goForward(stepper);" formControlName="firstCtrl" required> I agree </button>
```

Then, in the .ts, make sure to include...

```
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material/stepper';
```

...and then add this function...

```
  goForward(stepper: MatStepper){
    stepper.next();
  }
```

When you click the checkbox, it should progress to your next step.

Comment: Does this also work when linear is true?  It seems not to for me.